# Migration of binaries to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Is there a script or any other automated process for migration of artifacts into JFrog? We are currently working on this and need more information to carry out this process. Please help us in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you migrating from? Are these files currently on a local file system? If so, I recommend using JFrog CLI's upload command.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe, we are migrating this from cloud (Enterprise Edition) to local (Enterprise Edition). We came to know that migrating from cloud to local is not possible as it doesn't have import and export options. But we need to migrate this from cloud to local. So is there any other alternate methods to do this? Please help us to carry this out and also kindly elaborate on this "JFrog CLI's upload command". Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a sample, if you want to upload a file called froggy.tgz to the root of the my-local-repo repository, you can run:
`$ jfrog rt u froggy.tgz my-local-repo`. Downloads work very similar, you can view the full explanation [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing artifact repository, JFrog Artifactory supports acting as an artifact proxy while you are in the process of migrating to Artifactory.

I would recommend the following:

1. Create a local repository in artifactory
2. Create a remote repository in artifactory which points to your current artifact repository.
3. Create a virtual repository in artifactory which contains both the local and remote repositories.
4. Iterate on all your projects to have them publish to the local artifactory repository and pull from the virtual repository.

The advantage to this workflow is that you can port things over piece by piece, rather than trying to do it all at once. If you point a dependency at artifactory that hasn't been ported there yet, artifactory will proxy it for you. When the dependency is ported over, it will be transparent to its users.

When you have moved everything to your local Artifactory repository, then you can remove the remote repository from your virtual repository.

The relevant documentation is available here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories

Answer (score 0):

For an Enterprise account, I'd suppose S3 storage and a significant number of artifacts, so there will be no easy and automated way to do it. It also highly dependent on the storage implementation of choice in the on-prem solution. If you plan to use S3 storage, JFrog can help to perform S3 replication. In other scenarios, the solution will be different. I suggest contacting the support.